# Hiding menus in sharepoint 2007 list

Tags: sharepoint, menu

I'd like to hide the Actions and Settings menus for some lists I have on a page.  I'd like to augment the "new" function by adding some parameters to the query string.

Any thoughts on how to go about doing this?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it.. y'all are too slow..  JK!
Hid Settings, Actions and New buttons and inserted a new button with the link as i want it.

(IDs specific to my Sharepoint site, obviously)

JQuery:

```
$('#zz21_ListActionsMenu').parent().parent().hide();
$('#zz26_ListSettingsMenu').parent().parent().hide();
$('#zz14_NewMenu').hide().parent().append(newLinkTag);
// Hide drop-down button    
$('#zz14_NewMenu_ti').hide();   
// Change tooltip text
$('span[title="Open Menu"]').attr('title', 'New Item');
```